# Good texts on logicism

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, arithmetic

I'm trying to learn about the logicist programme by myself so I was wondering, what are some good book/papers/articles on logicism? I'm looking for introductory to medium level texts, nothing very deep.

Comment: Marcus Giaquinto, [The Search for Certainty : A Philosophical Account of Foundations of Mathematics, Clarendon 2002](https://books.google.it/books?id=gyNbrpYXzxoC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: See also SEP's entry on [Logicism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism)

Comment: I am not sure you are interested in the classical logicism of Frege or the current neo-logicist proposals. On the former [Dummett's Frege: Philosophy of Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege:_Philosophy_of_Mathematics) is a classical reference, on the latter see [Hale-Wright The Reason's Proper Study: Essays Towards a Neo-Fregean Philosophy of Mathematics](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Reason_s_Proper_Study.html?id=X4btafC6dskC).

Comment: I'm more interested in the classical logicism, but reading about neologicism does no harm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is *Frege: Philosophy of Mathematics*. It is written by Michael Dummett, a modern British philosopher and civil rights activist. It explains the philosophy, but focuses on mathematician and philosopher Friedrich Ludwig Gottlob Frege who was interested in the [philosophy of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottlob_Frege). There is also *Philosophy of Mathematics Today* by Kit Fine, but it only talks about logicism between page 503 and page 629.